# Can stopline behavior be toggled dynamically?

Tags: anylogic

This model simulates cars pulling up to pumps at a gas/petrol station. I have a custom car agent 'MyCar' that passes through an upstream stopline. At this stopline it calls the agent's function which checks the availability of the two pump stations in the roadNetwork in Main. This function returns a RoadNetworkConstant 'PASS_THROUGH_STOP_LINE' or 'STOP_BEFORE_STOP_LINE'.

I'm unable to pass this constant value back into the 'Stop line behavior' property in a CarMoveTo block (for a different stop line further downstream but before the car reaches the pumps) in Main even when I start typing the name of my agent 'MyCar'.

Is it possible to change the Stop Line Behavior dynamically? If so, is this a resonable approach? If not, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 'car', not 'MyCar'. Check out the magic light bulb and how keywords work for you: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiuz-ytq9D8AhWsSvEDHZccDTUQFnoECAkQAg&usg=AOvVaw3XapUwKyi_Bi9_2JjGrN0b